# How can we use hyperopt for tuning hyperparameters in VotingClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, hyperopt

**When did I face the problem?**

I am trying to develop a soft voting classifier by [VotingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) of `sklearn`. To tune the hyperparameters of each model used in the `VotingClassifier`, I want to use the [hyperopt](http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/) library. However, I do not find the way to set the hyperparameters in the objective function and thus, I failed to tune the hyperparameters of that classifier. I just know how to do it (using `hyperopt`) separately for each model (e.g., just for Decision Tree classifier).

*Hyperparameters*

```
dic_clf_params = {'DT__max_depth': hp.choice('DT__max_depth', range(2, 20)), # Decision Tree
                     'DT__criterion': hp.choice('DT__criterion', ['gini', 'entropy']),
                     'DT__class_weight': hp.choice('DT__class_weight', ['balanced']),
                     'AB__n_estimators': hp.choice('n_estimators', range(2, 1000)), # Adaptive Boosting
                     'AB__base_estimator': DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=20),
                     'AB__learning_rate': hp.uniform('learning_rate', 0.2, 1)}
```

*Objective function*

```
def objective_function(params):
  clf = model(**params)
  f1 = cross_val_score(clf, x_data, y_data.values.tolist(), scoring="f1", cv=10).mean()
  return {"loss": -f1, "status": STATUS_OK}
```

**How did I try to solve the problem?**

I have checked the official documents (e.g., [this document](http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/getting-started/minimizing_functions/) describing the objective function of `hyperopt`. Also, I searched a lot to find the tutorials and Q&A (in SO) regarding the usage of `hyperopt` in voting classifier, stacking classifier. However, I failed to find a single tutorial or Q&A.

**Note**: I want to use the `hyperopt` since each individual model's hyperparameters were tuned by that library.